# Plot ListPlot with error bars from experimental points

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have a list of experimental points. Each point was measured one or several times:

```
{{0, 2}, {0, 10}, {10, 90}, {20, 150}, {20, 144}, {20, 152}, {20, 161}, 
 {30, 198}, {30, 192}, {40, 210}, {50, 230}, {50, 228}, {50, 221}, 
 {60, 235}, {60, 230}} // ListPlot
```

Is it possible to use this list to plot `ErrorListPlot`? In other words how I can calculate new list `{{x,mean_y_at_x, ErrorBar[sd]}, ...}` from initial one?
Sorry for possible duplicate, but I could not find answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data = {{0, 2}, {0, 10}, {10, 90}, {20, 150}, {20, 144}, {20, 152}, 
  {20, 161}, {30, 198}, {30, 192}, {40, 210}, {50, 230}, {50, 228}, 
  {50, 221}, {60, 235}, {60, 230}}; 

gathered = GatherBy[data, First];

elpdata =Through[{Mean, ErrorBar@If[Length@#==1, 0, StandardDeviation@#]&}@#]& /@ gathered

Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]
ErrorListPlot[elpdata]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]